# FromBody does not bind Inherited Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

The customer class is inheriting from Entity in which the "Id" property is available. But whenever I post a JSON object to my controller all the properties except "Id" will be initiated. "Id" is always 0

Have you got any Idea what's wrong?

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> : IEquatable<Entity<TId>>
{
    public TId Id { get; protected set; }
}

public class Customer : Entity<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

  //Controller
public void Post([FromBody] Customer customer)
{
    if (customer.Id > 0)
        _customeRepository.Update(customer);

    _customeRepository.Insert(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Id` property does not have a public setter, that's why it could not be set during the data binding. Make the setter public and its value will be set correctly:

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> : IEquatable<Entity<TId>>
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

Note: `FromBody` attribute is not required in this case because parameter of `Customer` type will be bound from request body by the default.

Comment: the setter is Protected you are right. but do I have any alternative If I want to leave the property setter as it is? How can I set this property so?

Comment: If setter is protected it could be accessed from derived classes only. Another option is to call setter via reflection. But anyway it's a code smell and not recommended approach.